# Format multiple columns with the same name with in VBA to a certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have a worksheet with multiple columns of the same name: "Days to Finish"

I'm trying to format all those "Days to Finish" columns to force a specific date. When I run my code, it seems to only pick up the first one and ignores the rest.

```
Dim ChangeFormat as range
   set ws = activesheet
   set f = ws.rows(1).find("Days to Finish"), lookat:=xlWhole)
     If not f is nothing then 
       for each ChangeFormat in ws.range(f, ws.cells(rows.count, f.column).end(xlUp)).cells
         with ChangeFormat
           .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
         end with
       next ChangeFormat
     end if
```

Comment: You've only done the `Find` once.

Comment: Also you can change the numberformat in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Find'. Loop through the header row and test for "Days to Finish" in each cell, if not found, then hide the column, etc; then format all the visible columns as needed.

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.UsedRange 'you can change to a defined range if needed
        For Each cel In .Rows(1).Cells 'change to Row # that contains the headers
            If cel.Text <> "Days to Finish" Then 'hide column is cell does not contain text
                .Columns(cel.Column).Hidden = True
            End If
        Next cel

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy" 'format all visible columns
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'unhide hidden columns
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!